# Upstart says my script is running but the API not returning data until I restart the process

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with the following Upstart file for a RESTful API.

`description "myFoodLab API - node.js server"`

`author      "b3nk3"`

`# used to be: start on startup`

`# until we found some mounts weren't ready yet while booting:`

`start on runlevel [2345]`

`start on started mountall`

`stop on shutdown`

`# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 20 5`

`script
    export HOME="/www-data"`

`exec sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/node`
`/var/www/html/mydomain.co.uk/subdomain/sco/node_modules/server.js 
end script`

When I check the status I get that it is runnning, but checking with Postman it fails to retrieve data.

> b3nk3@benserver:~$ sudo initctl status myfoodlabapi
>
> myfoodlabapi start/running, process 3685

could there be a problem with my server.js? checked the log and it seems to stop reconnecting after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upstart script is intact. The problem could be with the MySQL connection.